# Scroll displacement on React Native with Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, expo

I got this screenshot from a user that says its scroll is displaced in the center as you can see in the image bellow.

I tried using simulator with iPhone XS Max and even my olds iPhone 7 but couldn't reproduce this in anyway. Maybe this is a known bug or something and I was wandering if someone could point me in the right direction.

About the code, I'm using a ScrollView component with the following props:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView
        style={{flexGrow: 1}}
        contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
    >
        // content here
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please try to set absolute position for your scrollview

```
`<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView
        style={{flexGrow: 1, position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 0}}
        contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
    >
        // content here
    </ScrollView>
</View>`
```

Comment: This would not help, but gave me an idea to test adding `width` property and that might do the trick.

Comment: What is the width of your scrollview?

Comment: The same as the devices width

Comment: than its simple, give padding left of screenwidth